# Does anyone know an arbitrary precision LA library for c++?

Tags: library, c++

Does anyone know any more C++ linear algebra libraries with arbitrary precision, preferably using GMP? I have a program using GMP that needs to use singular value decomposition at one point. Currently, I do this with the Eigen library for a proof of concept, however, for the real application I need arbitrary precision, and as far as I know, Eigen does not offer this.
The libraries listed on the [website](https://gmplib.org/manual/Language-Bindings) don't have SVD (CLN, LinBox, and NTL) as far as I can tell. ALP does seem to have SVD, however, the [download link](https://www-sop.inria.fr/saga/logiciels/ALP/html/install.html) does not work and I'm not sure it has arbitrary precision.
In conclusion, if you know any LA library for C++ using arbitrary precision, I'd be grateful.
On a side note, good arbitrary precision algebra libraries, in general, would be welcome, for example, to calculate (1/3)!, though this is not as pressing, I think I can find some myself.